# Merging 2 lists of dicts based on common values

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have 2 lists of dicts in Python as follows:

```
list1 = [
{
    "medication_name": "Actemra IV", 
    "growth": 0, 
    "total_prescriptions": 3
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "Actemra SC", 
    "growth": 0.0, 
    "total_prescriptions": 2
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "Adempas", 
    "growth": 0, 
    "total_prescriptions": 1
}
]

list2 = [
{
    "medication_name": "Actemra IV", 
    "fulfillment_time": 94340
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "Actemra SC", 
    "fulfillment_time": 151800
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "Adempas", 
    "fulfillment_time": 156660
}
]
```

What I would want is to have list1 appended with the fulfillment_time key from list2 so that the output is as follows:

```
[
{
    "medication_name": "Actemra IV", 
    "growth": 0, 
    "fulfillment_time": 94340, 
    "total_prescriptions": 3
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "Actemra SC", 
    "growth": 0.0, 
    "fulfillment_time": 151800, 
    "total_prescriptions": 2
}, 
{
    "medication_name": "Adempas", 
    "growth": 0, 
    "fulfillment_time": 156660, 
    "total_prescriptions": 1
}
]
```

I achieved this in the traditional way of looping over both lists as follows:

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i['medication_name'] == j['medication_name']:
            i['fulfillment_time'] = j['fulfillment_time']
```

What I wanted to know is that are there any inbuilt one line functions already in python that perform the same task that I may not know of ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "one line" way to do what you want, mainly because it's not a very natural operation: the data structures you are using don't naturally allow the operations you want to do.  This is also borne out by the fact that your algorithm is rather inefficient: it loops all the way through `list2` for every element of `list1`.  It is quadratic in the number of elements.

It seems like you are thinking of the `'medication_name'` as the key for the dictionaries in the list.  But the list type provides no operation to find elements by that key.

A more pythonic approach would be to convert the list into a dictionary: then finding the right dictionary will become O(1).  Something like this:

```
d = { i['medication_name'] : i for i in list2}
for i in list1:
    i.update(d[i['medication_name']])
```

Python does provide a one-liner to merge the dictionaries, as shown.

This does raise the question of what you want to do if `list2` contains no entry for one of the entries in `list1`: a try/except could be used to deal with that.

These data structures are a little bit "database-like".  Perhaps you should be using `sqlite3`?